# Creating a bigger List of Lists using a pattern

Tags: python, list, pattern-matching

Let's say I have the following pattern:

```
PATTERN = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]]
```

and I want to use this to create the following:

```
PATTERN | HORIZONTAL_MIRROR (PATTERN)
VERTICAL_MIRROR(PATTERN) | HORIZONTAL_MIRROR(VERTICAL_MIRROR(PATTERN))
```

In other words:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1],[4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4],[7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7], [7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7], [4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]]
```

is there an efficient method that can be used in Python apart from copying each element from the `PATTERN`?

Comment: What do you mean by "vertical mirror"?

Comment: @uʍop ǝpısdn: upside down :)

Comment: (:P) How do you turn bits upside down? Isn't it just the same operation (mirroring) but with a different interpretation? See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an idea:

```
PATTERN = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]]
def patternify(l):
    for sl in l:
        yield sl+sl[::-1]
    for sl in l[::-1]:
        yield sl+sl[::-1]

list(patternify(PATTERN))
#output: [[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1], [4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4], [7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7], [7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7], [4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the requirement correctly:

```
def mirror(pat):
    return pat + pat[::-1]

SUPERPATTERN = mirror(map(mirror, PATTERN))
```